# Should a developer create failsafes to prevent app crashing?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

My app draws a UIImageView with a photo to the screen every time a button is pressed.

The normal use case for my app would probably be about a dozen or so imageviews, but a user could potentially abuse it by continually pressing the "Add" button.

After about 50 or so the new images turn black. And after 100 or so the app freezes.

Now the majority of people using my app probably wont come close to these numbers, but through sheer abuse, they can crash the app. Is it my responsibility to design and implement failsafes that prevent the user from purposefully crashing the app?

Comment: Yes. I would abuse this button just to see what would happen.

Comment: Yes. All exceptions should be caught, in any cases.

Comment: No, all exceptions should NOT be caught in any case in Objective-C. This is not Java. But the app should not be designed to crash if something is done 100 times. You are clearly having a memory issue which should be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that you should ensure that any software you produce meets the requirements of the user to the best of your ability. I suspect there is a memory allocation issue at hand here. In any case, I would argue it's better to find a bug and fix it rather than get complaints from users when they inexorably find them. If a bug affects the functionality of the program noticeably for the user, then I think it should be fixed. Cutting corners should be considered when adding extra features that may take more time than appropriate, not when fixing existing features.